# preg_replace ( - ) between 2 constant texts

Tags: preg-replace

How i can preg_replace with a comma between 2 constant texts

```
blablabalba","color:Metal Black - White;sex:blablabal"
```

I want to be:

```
blablabalba","Metal Black,White"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I well understand your needs, but is this what you want:

```
$str = 'blablabalba","color:Metal Black - White;sex:blablabal"';
$str = preg_replace('/"color:([^-]+) - (\w+)[^"]+"/u', '"$1,$2"', $str);
```

Comment: It looks like good but i get this weird symbol and not the second color in a tester `blablabalba|"Metal Black,�`

Comment: I also want to catch `color:` in the replace because there are more `:` in the sting

Comment: @Alexandros:See my edit to catch `color`. For the special char, it is certainly an encoding problem.

Comment: @Alexandros: You didn't say you have to deal with greek character. And, the regex you are using isn't the one I gave you. Add the unicode flag.

Comment: You are near... But i am now facing more issues that i couldnt imagine... What if i got more colors there? 3 or 4?

Comment: @Alexandros: Have a look at `preg_replace_callback`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91454/discussion-between-alexandros-and-toto).